# How to execute a python script in .NET application..?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When user click Build button Python script needs to run.I execute this by using process but so many processes created when so many clicked the Build button, server hang.

Answer (score 1):

Trying my best to read between your (few) lines...

You could disable the button until the process finishes, so your users can't press it again until the script has completed.

Or, if you want to run the process synchronously instead, you might want to look into [`Process.WaitForExit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx).